# Reading csv files into array and skipping the first row PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file and the first two columns are headers

```
'Student','ID','SIS User ID' 
Points Possible      
Ashe,   797389, 11721809
Darius,  20237, 55050811
Fizz,    34604, 55035088
Tom Kenn,20232, 55050802
Vayne,  797413, 11813445
```

For the first two columns, they should not be added to the array.
Start from Ashe, I would like to add `Ashe, 797389, 11721809` row to `array[0]`
Darius to `array[1]`,....

I write my code as follows:

```
<?php
$csvData = file_get_contents('output.csv');
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
print_r($array[2][5]);
?>
```

What should I do in order to skip the first two rows?

After fixing the problems, there is a empty array . How to eliminate the empty array ?

```
[797413] => Array
    (
        [0] => Vayne
        [1] => 797413
        [2] => 11813445
        [3] => lsmdec
        [4] => cs3487
        [5] => 12.15
        [6] => 15
        [7] => 5
        [8] => 17
        [9] => 49.15
        [10] => 49.15
        [11] => 49.15
        [12] => 49.15
        [13] => 49.15
        [14] => 49.15
        [15] => 49.15
        [16] => 49.15
        [17] => C-
        [18] => C-
    )

[] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove the first element from the array and keep it somewhere safe for later use, like so:

```
<?php
$csvData = file_get_contents('output.csv');
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
$first_row = array_shift($lines);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $newLine = str_getcsv($line);
    if(isset($newLine[0]) && !empty($newLine[0])){
        $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }
}
print_r($array[2][5]);

?>
```

This will put the first element of your array into `$first_row` and remove it from `$lines`;
if you need to skip more than the first row, you could stack the `array_shift()` method to remove the first row twice.

Comment: [797413] => Array
        (
            [0] => Vayne
            [1] => 797413
            [2] => 11813445
            [3] => lsmdec
            [4] => cs3487
            [5] => 12.15
            [6] => 15
            [7] => 5
            [8] => 17
            [9] => 49.15
            [10] => 49.15
            [11] => 49.15
            [12] => 49.15
            [13] => 49.15
            [14] => 49.15
            [15] => 49.15
            [16] => 49.15
            [17] => C-
            [18] => C-
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

Comment: @killer2318 what?

Comment: sorry, it is in wrong format, feel free to take a look my new problems met. I have edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: @killer2318 This is a completely different problem, and you should ask a new question instead of editing your question to add a second problem.

Comment: @killer2318 where did you get that output by the way? Is that what is stored in `$array` or is that in `$array[2][5]` ?

Comment: I just tried to print all the array by using this code:print_r($array);

Comment: @killer2318 added a check to my answer to make sure the line isn't empty. It should work now

Comment: should I check like this?      while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

Answer (score 0):

```
    $csvData = file_get_contents('output.csv');
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
    $array = array();
    foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {            
        if ($key !== 0) {
            $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    die;
```

Now you can check the array value else you can also shift first array you can use array_shift function